# How can I make plt.axline work with my slope function call

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I want to run a plt.axline through some point with the slope of another line. When I use two points, as illustrated in the plot image below, axline works.

[image]

When I calculate the slope of the black line as m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and add slope=m, in the axline() call, it will not work. My python code is below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=2222805
y1=499020

x2=2218532
y2=510085

x3=2221782
y3=505461

%matplotlib inline
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))

plt.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],color="black",marker="x")
plt.scatter(x3,y3,color="red",marker="x")

# m = the slope of the black line
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
print('slope = '+str(m))

# # trying to plot a red dashed line through the red x point with the slope of the black line
# plt.axline((x3,y3),(x2,y2),linestyle='--',linewidth=1, color='r')
plt.axline((x3,y3),slope=m,linestyle='--',linewidth=1, color='r')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Did you try upgrading matplotlib to version `'3.4.2'`? If that doesn't help, could you explain what you mean by `it will not work`?  Does it show a wrong line? Or no line? Or give an error? Or ...?

Comment: @JohanC, I am using version 3.3.4. I thought I was using the latest version. Ill go upgrade.

Comment: @JohanC, that worked! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohanC pointed out, I was running matplotlib version 3.3.4 and needed 3.4.2.